# Generate a team from a list of unique players based on priority number. 3 Arrays of signups for different role

Tags: algorithm, combinations, selection

Im trying to create an application that would form a team of 4 people in a shooter game.
There are 3 roles for 4 players. We need 2x assault, 1x sniper and 1x medic in a team.
I would be choosing players from 3 arrays, each array contains signups for that role (playername and priority number). Players can signup for multiple roles.

```
Sniper[0] John 100
Sniper[1] Mort 91
Sniper[2] Stef 70
Medic[0] Jerry 92
Medic[1] Mort 91
Medic[2] Jambo 19
Assault[0] Jerry 92
Assault[1] Haler 91
Assault[2] Gowgow 79
Assault[3] Jambo 19
```

This is how the 3 arrays would look like.

Selection in this case should be:

```
Sniper - John 100
Medic - Mort 91
Assault1 - Jerry 92
Assault2 - Haler 91
```

Application should always try to select people with highest priority for available roles.

If anyone could at least point me in the right direction on how to solve this issue. Im really stuck here as I have no idea how to do it and I don't know what to search for online either, to learn.

Comment: sort each list by priority (desc order), and each time extract from top of the each list needed members.

Comment: Problem is that people signup for multiple roles and if I just take the top people by order then I need to check for duplicates for second two roles and it wont always be people with highest "priority" or team won't be able to form because of for example missing 1 player in a certain role because someone applied with 2 and was chosen for another role

Comment: Looks like [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my selection problem with a "Hungarian algorithm or Munkres".